# How can I get the downloaded files using sync in s3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I am downloading files from a certain bucket using something like this:

```
aws s3 sync s3://my-bucket --profile xyz c:\Destination --exclude "*" --include ".txt"
```

Then I need to import data from those files, however I need to import those that where downloaded recently otherwise I might be importing data more than once.

Is there any instruction/option that returns that list of files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite.

If you are doing an incremental `sync` and you only want to perform operations on the "newly downloaded" files, here are some options:

- Keep a "before" list of the file and compare
- You might be able to use the creation time of the files to make a comparison
- Take the output of the command and turn it into useful information

Sample output is:

```
upload: test.txt to s3://mybucket/test.txt
upload: test2.txt to s3://mybucket/test2.txt
```

Comment: Thanks! I think we will end up doing something like this, there are limited options for the sync command and in general, I think, for all the commands in S3.